# Multiple Google-site-verification meta tag for GCP and GSC?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, meta-tags, google-search-console

We would like to add a Google-site-verification meta tag for our Cloud Identity on Google Cloud Platform (GCP). However, our website has already a google-site-verification meta tag for Google Search Console (GSC). Is it allowed to have multiple google verification tag of GCP and GSC on same domain ? If we do the google verification on GCP, will it affect the existing GSC ownership ? We could use different accounts for each verification.